# Access filter on time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a table with a time in a datetime field on an MSSQL2k8R2 server. I have linked the table in Access 2007. The table was migrated with the migration assistant from Microsoft.

i.e. the Managemantstudio will give on `SELECT TOP 3 [AbZeit], [AbBrP] FROM [dbo].[tSollFahrten]` the Result

```
AbZeit                  AbBrP
1899-12-30 12:53:00.000 LOR
1899-12-30 09:27:00.000 BAT
1899-12-30 10:54:00.000 LOR
```

When I am going to open an ADO recordset and set a filter, it worked fine (but slow).

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "Select * from tSollFahrten;", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
rs.Filter = "AbZeit=#12:53#"
Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
rs.Close
```

The result is one recordset. But to open the recordset already filterd won’t work at all. I have no result.

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "Select * from tSollFahrten where AbZeit = #12:53#;", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
rs.Close
```

Has anyone an idea what’s going on there?

Comment: Will it run with `= #1899-12-30 12:53#`?

Comment: No. Still no result.

Comment: Using ADO 6.1, I tried to run similar code here with Access 2013, and both versions ran with expected results (identical record count). So something else is going on

Comment: @Gustav Did you connect Access to a SQL Server ?

Comment: Yes, a linked table via ODBC. Server version 10.50.4297.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the time is in the SQL server stored as `datetime`. So the field in the linked table is a `datetime`. When the time is stored as a `time(7)` in the SQL server, the field in the linked table will get a `text`. And then the select will work with `AbZeit='12:53'` as expected.

Comment: Interesting. So your solution was to change the field type from `datetime` to `time(7)` ? And you still query with `#12:53#`?

Comment: Yes and no. @SQLPolice now it must be `'12:53'` because now it's text for access.

Answer (score 1):

There is an important difference between the two statements:

```
rs.Open "Select * from tSollFahrten;", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
rs.Filter = "AbZeit=#12:53#"
```

==> In this case, you get first the data from SQL server, with **SQL SERVER SYNTAX**, and then you filter them **LOCALLY** with **ACCESS SYNTAX**.

```
rs.Open "Select * from tSollFahrten where AbZeit = #12:53#;", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

==> In this case, you do everything with **SQL SERVER SYNTAX**. However, the Hashtag ## is specific to Access, and SQL Server does not understand it.

**EDIT:** In SQL Server, you can query the hour and minute like this:

```
rs.Open "Select * from tSollFahrten where datepart(hh, AbZeit)=12 and datepart(mi, abZeit)=53", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: I agree, this was thoroughly interesting.

Comment: You forget that this is a linked table. Then it's Access SQL, not T-SQL. And if it was T-SQL, `where AbZeit = #12:53#` would error out.

Comment: I know about the difference. And this is the reason, why I don't want to use the Filter from Access. And @Gustav you are right. The linked Table is Access SQL.

Comment: @Stefan Are you sure you have **no** `on error resume next` just in case you oversee an error in the query ?

Comment: Yes. I am sure. I forgot the third law of debugging. "is the bug not, where you are looking, it is somewhere else". I've just posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a `Date/Time` type I would suggest you look for the complete Date and time. Something like,

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM tSollFahrten " & _
        "WHERE AbZeit >= #1899-12-30 12:53:00# AND AbZeit <= #1899-12-30 12:54:00#;" , _
        CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

Debug.Print rs.RecordCount

rs.Close
```

Comment: I'm sorry - still no result.